# eloquent multiple whereHas('pivot_table_X') AND whereHas('pivot_table_X')

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel-5, eloquent

I am building an app using Eloquent and hit a bummer, I am using the many-to-many Pivot relation. *ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#many-to-many*

User Model

- id
- user_name

Role Model

- id
- role_name

User-Role Model (Pivot Table)

- id
- user_id
- role_id

If i want to get all Users with Role id `1`, i will just simply:

```
$users = $app->users->with('roles')->has('roles')
    ->whereHas('roles' function($query) {
        $query->where('role_id', 1);
    })
    ->get();
```

With this, I can successfully get all users with Role id = 1.

**[Issue]** Now bummer is when I need to get all Users with `Role id = 1 AND Role id = 2` (Both Administrator and Moderator in my case)

I tried running this:

```
$users = $app->users->with('roles')->has('roles')
    ->whereHas('roles' function($query) {
        $query->where('role_id', 1);
    })
    ->whereHas('roles' function($query) {
        $query->where('role_id', 2);
    })
    ->get();
```

But exhausted my PHP execution time, is there a correct way to handle this? I am really hoping for the efficient way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: Should not it be **OR** instead of **AND** for bot the role ids?

Comment: @SougataBose Hello! I believe its **AND**, because pivot model table has multiple **role_id** for a single **user_id**, what I wish to achieve is get all the **Users** where both id `2 AND 3` are in the **role_id**

Answer (score 0):

You can try it as:

```
$users = $app->users->with('roles')
           ->whereHas('roles' function($query) {
              $query->where('role_id', 1)
                    ->where('role_id', 2);
          })
          ->get();
```

I have removed `->has('roles')` intentionally because we are using `whereHas()` on the roles table so `has` will have no use. It will work the same.

Comment: sorry, but I don't think that SQL will solve it, it would look for "single" row in the pivot table where "role_id" that is both 1 and 2, which is not possible. Tried it, and ofc, it won't return any object from the model.